# PayPal express checkout in angular 2 components - Loading issue?

Tags: angular, paypal

I am trying to dynamically create a paypal checkout button using the price of data objects contained and rendered by my angular 2 components. I would like to pass the paypal express code an amount and have it render a button for me when I open my checkout component but I am having huge problems.

I followed this guide: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/basic-integration/ but if I try include paypals script code in a component it doesn't load and if I put the code in my Index.html the script loads and gives me this error:

ppxo_xc_ppbutton_error Object {error: "Error: Document is ready and element #paypal-butto…calhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:139776:25) []", timestamp: 1486999989713, windowID: "be296e274d", pageID: "a63dc0f8ab", host: "localhost:3000"…}

Error: Document is ready and element #paypal-button does not exist
    at https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:5176:39 []
    at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:138551:47) [ => ]
    at ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:138745:33) []
    at data.args.(anonymous function) (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:139776:25) []

- unhandled_error Object {message: "Error: Document is ready and element #paypal-button does not exist", stack: "Error: Document is ready and element #paypal-butto…calhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:139776:25) []", errtype: "[object Object]", event: "ppxo_unhandled_error", version: "4.0.39"…}
  zone.js:155 Uncaught ZoneAwareError {__zone_symbol__error: Error: Document is ready and element #paypal-button does not exist
  at https://www.paypalobjects.…, __zone_symbol__stack: "Error: Document is ready and element #paypal-butto…calhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:139776:25) []"}

Comment: Do you have an element with `id="paypal-button"`? And is that element present when you call `paypal.Button.render()`?

Comment: my id="paypal-button element was being rendered in an angular component later than I was inserting the paypal scripts and that cause the error posted above. The scripts only loaded if they were placed in index.html. I gave up and just ended up using the back-end SDK and implemented it on my express server. Thanks though

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the below code in your angular component
declare let paypal: any;

Then you can use the paypal.Button.render({...}) method in ngOnInit

Comment: I'm in the same situation as OP, but your solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: Not Working, i have did

Comment: It worked for me, man. Thank you!

As you said, in the component (before declaring the class) I "declared" a variable:

let paypal: any;

And then, in the ngOnInit() method, i called the paypal.Button.render({... ]) function.

In my template I put the div that were going to contain the button and them it worked!

Thank you.